# How come functions in core run faster when not bound locally?

Tags: optimization, clojure

The example says it all:

```
user> (time (dotimes [i 10000000] (inc i)))
"Elapsed time: 413.948711 msecs"
nil
user> (time (let [new-inc inc] (dotimes [i 10000000] (new-inc i))))
"Elapsed time: 1034.722729 msecs"
nil
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the compiler inlines certain core functions like `inc`, especially when applied to primitive arguments.

When you use `inc` as a regular function (e.g. passing to higher order functions, aliasing with `let` etc.), performance may therefore be worse because it loses the ability to inline. The extra overhead comes from making an extra function call, any maybe also the cost of boxing one or more arguments.

This isn't a limitation of Clojure, just reflects the fact that the compiler isn't yet very sophisticated with its optimisations. You can probably expect things like this to get much better in future versions of Clojure.

Comment: This is exactly right. `inc` is inlined, and in fact since `i` is known to be a primitive long, the compiler can actually emit a single bytecode operation to add 1, bypassing entirely the methods in `clojure.lang.Numbers`.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to what mikera has mentioned about inlining. The `inc` is a var that is bound to a function. If you look at the `meta` of var `inc` i.e `(meta #'inc)` you will find that it has a key `:inliner` whose value the compiler can use to inline the code of the function where it is being called *using inc var*. When you use `let` to bind it locally you are just binding the function object to a new name in local scope and the function object doesn't have any inlining information, it was the `inc` var which has that info and therefore the compiler cannot inline it.